# Can I install Ubuntu on G4 Mac?

Tags: mac, macosx

I will be getting a Mac G4 laptop, will post the exact specs when I get it, and I was wondering if it would be safe to install Ubuntu alongside OSX (probably tiger) and would the hardware (graphics, sound, HDD size) be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apple is always ahead of the hardware curve I'd bet on it that it will work. I have a Mac that is 6 years old that I run the current version without any issues.

The only "trick" is to install http://refit.sourceforge.net/ which will allow you to boot from into Ubuntu.

Ubuntu has always been better than the other distroes when it comes to installing and recognizing OSX partitions.

I recommend you use mac tools to resize the partition to make room. I used gparted and it took for ever, like an hour, whereas the mac tool takes minutes.

Comment: Can I use GRUB/BURG to boot into Ubuntu? BTW..Thanks for the answer

Comment: Never did it the grub way as I hate having to press the special keys to active the "alternate" boot mode. So I have always used refit. In fact I'm using a mac air at the moment with refit. The only downside is resume mode battery life suffers in Ubuntu, otherwise Ubuntu is WAY better than OSX.

Comment: Ok, so your saying I should go with rEFIT (maybe Boot Camp) over GRUB? Thanks! I will remember that when I get the mac!

Comment: Tiger has no bootcamp if I remember, bootcamp is also for Windows only